# How to make HttpURLConnection setConnectTimeout work under Android?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to establish connection when reading text and binary content from remote web resources.

I need to implement approach that takes into account possible problems with

- connection timeout during connection to remote web resources 
  and
- during content download from remote web resources.

There are 2 setters `setConnectTimeout()` and `setReadTimeout()` of `URLConnection` class that are used for these purposes.

When I am running code given bellow with implementation of these 2 setters on my computer in console, everything works fine.

I use specification of URL as "www.google.com:81" to simulate connection timeout problem on my computer since 81 port is closed by my firewall.

Exception is raised after 10 seconds as expected and is shown in my console.

Then I process this exception by warning user about possible problems with connection to remote web resources.

But when I call just the same methods with timeout setters under Android platform, timeout exception is not raised after 10 seconds.

I've searched all StackOverflow and found description of similar problems when using timeouts under Android.

But none of the given answers points to specific decision of the problem.

Can anyone point to exact solution how to make `setConnectTimeout()` and `setReadTimeout()` setters work under Android as expected for these lines of code?

```
package com.downloader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WebDownloader
{
  public static String StringFileContent;
  public static boolean StringFileIsDownloaded;
  public static byte[] BinaryFileContent;
  public static boolean BinaryFileIsDownloaded;

  public static void readStringFileContent(String urlString)
  {
    StringFileContent = "";
    StringFileIsDownloaded = false;
    try
    {
      URL Url = new URL(urlString);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)Url.openConnection();
      connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.connect();

      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

      StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      {
        response.append(inputLine);
      }
      in.close();

      StringFileContent = response.toString();
      StringFileIsDownloaded = true;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + localException.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static void readBinaryFileContent(String urlString)
  {
    BinaryFileContent = new byte[0];
    BinaryFileIsDownloaded = false;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
      URL Url = new URL(urlString);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)Url.openConnection();
      connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
      connection.setReadTimeout(10000);      

      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.connect();

      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

      byte[] chunk = new byte['?'];
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(chunk)) > 0)
      {
        outputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      BinaryFileContent = outputStream.toByteArray();
      BinaryFileIsDownloaded = true;
    }
    catch (Exception localException) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + localException.getMessage());        
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you get *any* exception? NB Please lay off the boldface. It doesn't help.

Comment: Yes. I get exception after approximately 40 seconds (Exception: Unable to resolve host "www.google.com": No address associated with hostname)

Comment: Have you tried loading the same url with the chrome navigator on the android device?

Comment: @Inessa: Considering your comment above, it looks like your DNS is unable to resolve the hostname, which means it is unable to get the IP address associated with the domain name.

Comment: No. Test url is not available from chrome navigator on the android device.

Comment: That is the point! I need to respond during 10 seconds if hostname is unavailable.

Comment: So you need to set a *DNS* timeout. Nothing to do with `HttpURLConnection`. See if there's anything at [Java networking properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html), but check that they work on Android.

Comment: I've checked your link and found out statement that "These properties may not be supported in future releases." And even in this description of "Java networking properties" there is no way to set DNS timeout. Setters setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout() are perfectly working on my PC when running this code in console without any need in changing of DNS timeout of my computer's network settings. Exception: "connect timed out" is raised after 10 seconds of waiting on PC as expected. I can't get why does the same code not return just the same exception on Android in similar conditions?

Comment: They are working perfectly in your PC *because there is no DNS timeout.* The real question here is why you're getting a DNS timeout.

Comment: I get DNS timeout on Android device because I am trying to handle the case when user has no money on his account to get access to Internet using cellular network.

Comment: Thus, network connection exists, but access to Internet is not allowed. I need to find out how to handle this case using timeouts checking.

Answer (score 1):

setConnectTimeout(int timeout)
If there is unreliable server and you want to wait only 15 seconds before you tell the user that "something is wrong".

setReadTimeout(int timeout) is the timeout when you have a connection, you're blocked on read() and you want to get an exception if the read blocks for more than timeout